# Displaying data in list for windows phone

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-7

I have two variables 'name' and 'amount' for about 100 items.
FYI item is a class and name and amount are its variables.

Now i have to display all my items as a list, with name in the right and amount in left of each row in my windows phone app.

what would be the right way to do it??

Comment: Show your code, show what you've tried.

Comment: Please show the code that you have. Don't expect StackOverflow to write your program for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new app that uses the "Databound Application" template and you'll get something very close to your needs that should be easy to modify for your exact requirements and provide a useful learning source.